# CAML Query multiple Lists with same fields

Tags: 2013, javascript, caml, query

I have 4 different lists with different fields.

Now I would like to retrieve items from all 4 of these lists ordered by user "Created By" ("Author") field using CAML.

Also, all of the lists have a common field "Cost" which I would like to retrieve from each item.

Is it possible to do this using just one CAML query?

Comment: No, you'll have to execute 4 queries and aggregate the results. It could be a single function as you are pulling the same data across them, but it would need to be parameterized so you can pass in the list name.

Comment: Thought so... I guess that's what I'm going to do then. Any ideas on how to order all the results by user (Author)? Should I iterate the SPUsersCollection and then retrieve the items from all the lists for each user? @EricAlexander

Comment: I'd use the promises framework to broadcast the calls, aggregate the results, and then reorder the result collection however you need. Here's a great example from Marc, http://sympmarc.com/2013/05/01/comparing-spservices-2013-01-calls-with-async-vs-promises-methods/

Comment: Have you considered using search instead?

Comment: @wjervis yes, I had a look at Search API, but I ended up using promises with 4 asynchronous calls and returned the results as table rows with "User" and "Cost" columns, then ordered the rows by "User" using jQuery :)

Comment: Could you post your code as answer for others to learn, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Answer to main question is *no*. But You can use SPSiteDataQuery with CAML query to define search criteria, for example:

```
SPSiteDataQuery spQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery
{
    Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />",
    Query = Camlex.Query().Where(i => i["Title"] == "test value").ToString(),
    ViewFields = Camlex.Query().ViewFields(new List<string> {"ID"}),
    RowLimit = 100
};
var dataTable = web.GetSiteData(spQuery);

foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    var listGuid = new Guid(datarow["ListId"]+"");
    var itemId = int.Parse(datarow["ID"]+"");

    // process items
}
```

This [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/webs-property-for-spsitedataquery-in-sharepoint-2010/) explains the usage of SPSiteDataQuery.